# Does the link state algorithm use dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, networking

So i was wondering if the link state alogirthm is based on dynamic programming. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the Link State routing algorithm is based on a bottom-up, dynamic programming approach. Here are my reasons:

> Why dynamic?

Because it divides the task of routing over a network into many smaller tasks, calculating reachability for all nodes (and then filling the tables etc). I see this as dividing the problem into smaller problems: *dynamic!*

I won't call this Greedy because calculating reachability from all nodes to all other nodes sounds like a set of [overlapping subproblems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems).

> Why bottom-up?

Because (assuming) a new node is added to the network, we would have to again calculate the reachability for all the nodes, and redo the whole thing because the new node can (possibly) be directly reachable by any number of nodes, and the whole representation would change. Top-down approaches would normally require adjustments in the routing table/map *only* corresponding to the new node.